# How do you save the value of a UIPickerView as a string?

Tags: ios, nsstring, uipickerview, retain

I am trying to save the selection in a UIPickerView as a string, but I seem to be losing the value after I dismiss the view.  How can I retain this value?

.m file

```
/*********************************/
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark PickerView DataSource
//Below are the functions for the UIPicker:

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:
(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

//count of categories array denotes how many elements the picker will have
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return arrCategorySelection.count;
}

//return the corresponding caregory
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return arrCategorySelection[row];
}

/*********************************/
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark PickerView Delegate

//Delegate method for the category picker
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    //trying to save the value as a string
    selectedCategory = [arrCategorySelection objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *selectedCategory;
```

Comment: You lose the value after dismissing what view? The controller that the code above is in? Where do you want to use selectedCategory?

Comment: After dismissing the UIPickerView, which is contained in a UIView.  The NSString I am trying to save the value in is in the UIView.

Comment: When you dismiss the picker view, it and all its properties will be deallocated, so you need to either pass the value to the view where you want to use it (via a delegate method), or keep a strong pointer to the picker view in your view, so it won't be deallocated when you dismiss it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A property is tied directly to the controller that it is declared in. To use the property, you need to access it before the controller is dismissed, normally with a delegate call. Apple has lots of example code on how to do this. Below is a summary.

Let's say MasterView is presenting PickerView. Normally, you want to do this with a segue.

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Present PickerView" sender:nil];
```

In PickerView.h you declare a protocol before the @interface portion:

```
@protocol PickerViewDelegate <NSObject>
    -(void)itemSelected:(NSString*)item;
@end
```

Then in the @interface portion, you declare a delegate property

```
@property(weak)id<PickerViewDelegate> delegate;
```

In MasterView, you need to populate this delegate in your prepareForSegue method

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Present PickerView"]) {
        PickerView *controller = segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

You also need to implement the delegate method (remember, it is best practice for the MasterView to both present and dismiss PickerView)

```
-(void)itemSelected:(NSString*)item {
    // do something with item
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    // depending on the presentation, you may need this instead
    // [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Now in PickerView.m, establish some way for the user to say he is done with his selection, say a tap of the save button on the upper right that calls this method:

```
-(IBAction)saveButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(itemSelected:)]) {
        [self.delegate itemSelected:self.selectedCategory];
}
```

Comment: thanks!  Was able to use this as well as example code to get it working the way i wanted